# When I click back button goto previous activity from current activity android

Tags: android, back-button

When iam moving current activity to list activity in list activity have 8 items and in list activity have add button widget when  I added one item using add button  so total 9 items in list activity. Here my problem is when I click on back button my application not moving to previous activity  showing list activity with 8 items after click again back button moving previous activity how to solve this issue without using intent

Comment: Upload your code also.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed() method the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you use realtime database like Firebase at the moment you will have updated list. I think when you click on button you are opening new activity and don't finish last one. So you come back to last view again. Of course if you send your code, you will get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should `override` method `onBackPressed()` in the activity where your back button is not working correctly for you:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     finish();
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

I think that adding method call `finish()` should solve your problem.